# Publicize in Jetpack stopped working on Custom Post Type it works in Blog Posts

Tags: plugin-jetpack

Hello guys I have a site which I installed JetPack in order to use Publicize to add the functionality to my CPT I added this code:

'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ,'author', 'publicize' ),

It was working perfect but a few days ago it stopped working I have used this article to troubleshoot but with not success https://jetpack.com/support/publicize/troubleshooting-publicize/

have you have this issue before?  thank you for your help.

Comment: This can be caused by multiple things, such as the other plugins installed on your site, the status of your site's connection to WordPress.com, the status of the connection to each one of your connected Social Media profiles, ... I would recommend [reaching out to the Jetpack support team](http://jetpack.com/support); they'll have more details about your site and look into this for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seemed they had an issue in their end, fortunately they fixed it.